# How do i make a parallax background? C# Monogame?

Tags: c#, parallax, monogame

I searched everything on the internet but I cannot find a way to make a simple parallax background for my title screen.

Comment: Having problems with the concept itself, or need specific steps using c#?

Comment: Problems with the concept itself, how to get an infinite background loop with more then one layer @MichaelTodd

Comment: Only thing I found specifically related to monogame is in Polish. Might be a reasonable place to start, though. http://community.monogame.net/t/a-monogame-tutorial-in-polish/1533

Comment: For "concept itself" type questions you may want to check out http://gamedev.stackexchange.com/ you might get better suited answers. Stack Overflow is better for "specific steps" kinds of questions.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In general, a way to show a horizontally repeating background that should work with any library capable of showing images:

```
image is a background image.
image2 is a second copy of the background.

On update:
    // Move the background to the left.
    image.x -= PerUpdateDeltaX;
    // If the background is off the screen, move it back on.
    // You can use modulo/remainder to do this better.
    if (image.x < -image.width)
        image.x = image.width;
    // Put the second image to the right of the first.
    image2.x = image.x + image.width;
```

To make this look good, the edges of the background image that touch need to be seamless.

Then, to make parallax (where there appear to me multiple layers moving in 3D), just add in a few more things:

1. Transparency.
2. More pairs of repeating background images, one pair for each layer of parallax.
3. Different `PerUpdateDeltaX` values for each layer. To look good, the higher/closer layers should move faster than lower layers.